# ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android how to get the lat and long of point

Tags: arcgis-10.0, android, arcgis-android, arcgis-runtime-sdk-java

I am new in the field. I am trying to develop an android app which is able to perform some spacial operations like

> plot a poin,
>   Dream a line, Polygon

But my problem is how can i get the lat and long values of a point that i plotted in the map.

I am referring the code is available on [GitHub.](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-android)

But i am not able to get the lat and long of a point.Please suggest some methods or code example to get this.

image of the app [image]

My code

**Gradle Module app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.panenviron.pocarcmap"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.esri.arcgisruntime:arcgis-android:100.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
}
```

**Gradle project**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    final def var = repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven{ url 'https://esri.bintray.com/arcgis' }
    }
    var
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Mainactivity.java**

```
package com.panenviron.pocarcmap;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.esri.arcgisruntime.geometry.Envelope;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.geometry.Point;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.geometry.PointCollection;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.geometry.Polyline;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.geometry.SpatialReferences;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.ArcGISMap;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.Basemap;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.Graphic;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.GraphicsOverlay;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.LocationDisplay;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.MapView;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.symbology.SimpleFillSymbol;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.symbology.SimpleLineSymbol;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.symbology.SimpleMarkerSymbol;
import com.panenviron.pocarcmap.sketching.SketchGraphicsOverlay;
import com.panenviron.pocarcmap.sketching.SketchGraphicsOverlayEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MapView mMapView;
    private SketchGraphicsOverlay mSketchGraphicsOverlay;
    private ImageButton mPointButton, mPolylineButton, mPolygonButton, mUndoButton, mRedoButton, mClearButton,_ImgBtnCompass;
    private ImageView _showMyLoc;
    private LocationDisplay mLocationDisplay;
    private int requestCode = 2;
    String[] reqPermissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission
            .ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

    Point TempmCurrentPointCollection;
    Button _PlotNextPoint;
    EditText _EdtTxtDirection,_EdtTxtDistance;

    ArrayList<String> MyPolyGonList;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> MyMultiPolyGonList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // inflate MapView from layout
        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        // create a map with the Basemap Type topographic
        //ArcGISMap mMap = new ArcGISMap(Basemap.Type.LIGHT_GRAY_CANVAS,lat, long, zoom);
        ArcGISMap mMap = new ArcGISMap(Basemap.Type.LIGHT_GRAY_CANVAS, 8.494911, 76.956755, 10);
        // set the map to be displayed in this view
        mMapView.setMap(mMap);
        // Create a new SketchGraphicsOverlay with a new listener
        mSketchGraphicsOverlay = new SketchGraphicsOverlay(mMapView, new MySketchGraphicsOverlayEventListener());

        // Get references to all of the bottom action bar bottoms for highlighting and disabling/enabling
        mPointButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pointButton);
        mPointButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showMyLoc();
            }
        });
        _ImgBtnCompass = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImgBtnCompass);
        _ImgBtnCompass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mLocationDisplay = mMapView.getLocationDisplay();
                mLocationDisplay.setAutoPanMode(LocationDisplay.AutoPanMode.COMPASS_NAVIGATION);
            }
        });
        //mPolylineButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.polylineButton);
        mPolygonButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.polygonButton);

        // Disable the undo, redo, and clear button to start with
        mUndoButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.undoButton);
        mUndoButton.setClickable(false);
        mUndoButton.setEnabled(false);

        mRedoButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.redoButton);
        mRedoButton.setClickable(false);
        mRedoButton.setEnabled(false);

        mClearButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.clearButton);
        mClearButton.setClickable(false);
        mClearButton.setEnabled(false);



        mLocationDisplay = mMapView.getLocationDisplay();
        mLocationDisplay.addDataSourceStatusChangedListener(new LocationDisplay.DataSourceStatusChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(LocationDisplay.DataSourceStatusChangedEvent dataSourceStatusChangedEvent) {

                // If LocationDisplay started OK, then continue.
                if (dataSourceStatusChangedEvent.isStarted())
                    return;

                // No error is reported, then continue.
                if (dataSourceStatusChangedEvent.getError() == null)
                    return;

                // If an error is found, handle the failure to start.
                // Check permissions to see if failure may be due to lack of permissions.
                boolean permissionCheck1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, reqPermissions[0]) ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean permissionCheck2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, reqPermissions[1]) ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                if (!(permissionCheck1 && permissionCheck2)) {
                    // If permissions are not already granted, request permission from the user.
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, reqPermissions, requestCode);
                } else {
                    // Report other unknown failure types to the user - for example, location services may not
                    // be enabled on the device.
                    String message = String.format("Error in DataSourceStatusChangedListener: %s", dataSourceStatusChangedEvent
                            .getSource().getLocationDataSource().getError().getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    // Update UI to reflect that the location display did not actually start

                }
            }
        });
        showMyLoc();
        _EdtTxtDirection=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EdtTxtDirection);
        _EdtTxtDistance=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EdtTxtDistance);
        _PlotNextPoint=(Button)findViewById(R.id.PlotNextPoint);
        _PlotNextPoint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String tempEdtTxtDirection=_EdtTxtDirection.getText().toString();
                String tempEdtTxtDistance=_EdtTxtDistance.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Distance : "+tempEdtTxtDistance+" ,  " +
                        "Direction : "+tempEdtTxtDirection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Point currentPoint=TempmCurrentPointCollection;

                // create color and symbols for drawing graphics
                SimpleMarkerSymbol markerSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.Style.TRIANGLE, Color.BLUE, 14);
                SimpleFillSymbol fillSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.Style.CROSS, Color.BLUE, null);
                SimpleLineSymbol lineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.Style.SOLID, Color.BLUE, 3);
                //Point pt = new Point( lat,long, SpatialReferences.getWgs84());
                Point pt = new Point(8565757.475800,947771.572170, SpatialReferences.getWgs84());
                GraphicsOverlay overlay = new GraphicsOverlay();
                mMapView.getGraphicsOverlays().add(overlay);
                overlay.getGraphics().add(new Graphic(createPoint(pt), markerSymbol));
                overlay.getGraphics().add(new Graphic(createPolyline(currentPoint,pt), lineSymbol));

                //mMapView.setViewpointGeometryAsync(createEnvelope(), getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.viewpoint_padding));
                //pointClick(mMapView);
                //moveGeodetic (List<Point> points, double distance, LinearUnit distanceUnit, double azimuth, AngularUnit azimuthUnit, GeodeticCurveType curveType)
                //mMapView.moveGeodetic(currentPoint,);

            }
        });

        MyPolyGonList=new ArrayList<>();
        MyMultiPolyGonList=new ArrayList<>();
    }
    private Point createPoint(Point point) {
        Log.e(" point--", String.valueOf(point));
        //[DocRef: Name=Create Point, Category=Fundamentals, Topic=Geometries]
        // create a Point using x,y coordinates and a SpatialReference
        Point pt = new Point(point.getX(), point.getY(), SpatialReferences.getWgs84());
        //[DocRef: END]

        return pt;
    }
    private Polyline createPolyline(Point one,Point two) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "createPolyline---", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //[DocRef: Name=Create Polyline, Category=Fundamentals, Topic=Geometries]
        // create a Polyline from a PointCollection
        PointCollection borderCAtoNV = new PointCollection(SpatialReferences.getWgs84());
        borderCAtoNV.add(one.getX(), one.getY());
        borderCAtoNV.add(two.getX(), two.getY());
        Polyline polyline = new Polyline(borderCAtoNV);
        //[DocRef: END]
       /* PointCollection borderCAtoNV = new PointCollection(SpatialReferences.getWgs84());
        borderCAtoNV.add(76.956755,8.494911);
        borderCAtoNV.add(76.856755,8.694911);
        borderCAtoNV.add(76.456755,8.994911);
        Polyline polyline = new Polyline(borderCAtoNV);*/
        return polyline;
    }
    private Envelope createEnvelope() {

        //[DocRef: Name=Create Envelope, Category=Fundamentals, Topic=Geometries]
        // create an Envelope using minimum and maximum x,y coordinates and a SpatialReference
        Envelope envelope = new Envelope( 12.0,78.0,9.0, 75.0, SpatialReferences.getWgs84());
        //[DocRef: END]

        return envelope;
    }
    public void showMyLoc(){
        mLocationDisplay.setAutoPanMode(LocationDisplay.AutoPanMode.RECENTER);
        if (!mLocationDisplay.isStarted())
            mLocationDisplay.startAsync();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        mMapView.pause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * When the point button is clicked, show it as selected and enable point drawing mode.
     *
     * @param v the button view
     */
    public void pointClick(View v) {
        if (!v.isSelected()) {
            v.setSelected(true);
            mSketchGraphicsOverlay.setDrawingMode(SketchGraphicsOverlay.DrawingMode.POINT);
        } else {
            mSketchGraphicsOverlay.setDrawingMode(SketchGraphicsOverlay.DrawingMode.NONE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * When the polyline button is clicked, show it as selected and enable polyline drawing mode.
     *
     * @param v the button view
     */
    public void polylineClick(View v) {
        if (!v.isSelected()) {
            v.setSelected(true);
            mSketchGraphicsOverlay.setDrawingMode(SketchGraphicsOverlay.DrawingMode.POLYLINE);
        } else {
            mSketchGraphicsOverlay.setDrawingMode(SketchGraphicsOverlay.DrawingMode.NONE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * When the polygon button is clicked, show it as selected and enable polygon drawing mode.
     *
     * @param v the button view
     */
    public void polygonClick(View v) {
        if (!v.isSelected()) {
            v.setSelected(true);
            mSketchGraphicsOverlay.setDrawingMode(SketchGraphicsOverlay.DrawingMode.POLYGON);
        } else {
            mSketchGraphicsOverlay.setDrawingMode(SketchGraphicsOverlay.DrawingMode.NONE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * When the undo button is clicked, undo the last event on the SketchGraphicsOverlay.
     *
     * @param v the button view
     */
    public void undoClick(View v) {
        mSketchGraphicsOverlay.undo();
    }

    /**
     * When the redo button is clicked, redo the last undone event on the SketchGraphicsOverlay.
     *
     * @param v the button view
     */
    public void redoClick(View v) {
        mSketchGraphicsOverlay.redo();
    }

    /**
     * When the clear button is clicked, clear all graphics on the SketchGraphicsOverlay.
     *
     * @param v the button view
     */
    public void clearClick(View v) {
        mSketchGraphicsOverlay.clear();
    }

    /**
     * Event listener for the SketchGraphicsOverlay that listens for state changes on the undo, redo, and
     * clear capabilities, as well as finished drawings, to control the enabled/disabled/selected state
     * of the various buttons.
     */
    private class MySketchGraphicsOverlayEventListener implements SketchGraphicsOverlayEventListener {

        @Override
        public void onUndoStateChanged(boolean undoEnabled) {
            // Set the undo button's enabled/disabled state based on the event boolean
            mUndoButton.setEnabled(undoEnabled);
            mUndoButton.setClickable(undoEnabled);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRedoStateChanged(boolean redoEnabled) {
            // Set the redo button's enabled/disabled state based on the event boolean
            mRedoButton.setEnabled(redoEnabled);
            mRedoButton.setClickable(redoEnabled);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClearStateChanged(boolean clearEnabled) {
            // Set the clear button's enabled/disabled state based on the event boolean
            mClearButton.setEnabled(clearEnabled);
            mClearButton.setClickable(clearEnabled);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawingFinished() {
            // Reset the selected state of the drawing buttons when a drawing is finished
           // mPointButton.setSelected(false);
            //mPolylineButton.setSelected(false);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "im at draw finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            /*ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> rowList = new ArrayList<>();
            rowList.add(MyPolyGonList);*/
            MyMultiPolyGonList.add(MyPolyGonList);
            Log.e("MyMultiPolyGonList--",MyMultiPolyGonList.toString());
            mPolygonButton.setSelected(false);
        }

        @Override
        public Point getThePoint(Point point){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "point="+point, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            TempmCurrentPointCollection=point;
            MyPolyGonList.add(point.toJson());
            Log.e("MyPolyGonList--",MyPolyGonList.toString());
            Log.e(" point.x--", String.valueOf(point.getX()));
            Log.e(" point.y--", String.valueOf(point.getY()));
            Log.e(" point.m--", String.valueOf(point.getM()));
            Log.e(" point.json--", point.toJson());
            return  point;
        }
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="5"
            android:hint="Distance"
            android:id="@+id/EdtTxtDistance"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="5"
            android:hint="Direction"
            android:id="@+id/EdtTxtDirection"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="plot"
            android:id="@+id/PlotNextPoint"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- MapView -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
        <com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.MapView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">

            <ImageButton
                android:contentDescription="@string/pointButtonDescription"

                android:id="@+id/pointButton"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/current_loc" />
            <ImageButton
                android:contentDescription="@string/polylineButtonDescription"

                android:id="@+id/ImgBtnCompass"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/pointButton"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pointButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/compass"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/polygonButton"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ImgBtnCompass"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImgBtnCompass"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/polygon"
                android:onClick="polygonClick"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:contentDescription="@string/undoButtonDescription"

                android:id="@+id/undoButton"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/polygonButton"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/polygonButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/undo"
                android:onClick="undoClick"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:contentDescription="@string/redoButtonDescription"

                android:id="@+id/redoButton"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/undoButton"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/undoButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/redo"
                android:onClick="redoClick"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:contentDescription="@string/clearButtonDescription"

                android:id="@+id/clearButton"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/redoButton"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/redoButton"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/delete"
                android:onClick="clearClick"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**SketchGraphicsOverlay.java**

code is [here](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-android/blob/master/map-sketching/src/main/java/com/esri/arcgisruntime/sample/mapsketching/SketchGraphicsOverlay.java)

**SketchGraphicsOverlayEventListener.java**

code is [here](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-android/blob/master/map-sketching/src/main/java/com/esri/arcgisruntime/sample/mapsketching/SketchGraphicsOverlayEventListener.java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the coordinates of a Point with `Point.getX()` and `Point.getY()` which will be in the reference system of the existing Point.  You can then use the `GeometryEngine` to reproject the point to get coordinates in the reference you want, e.g. Lat/Long.  Below is an example of getting the Lat/Long of a tapped point on a Map:

```
// get the point that was clicked and convert it to a point in map coordinates
android.graphics.Point screenPoint = new android.graphics.Point(Math.round(motionEvent.getX()), Math.round(motionEvent.getY()));
// create a map point from screen point
Point mapPoint = mMapView.screenToLocation(screenPoint);
// convert to WGS84 for lat/lon format
Point wgs84Point = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(mapPoint, SpatialReferences.getWgs84());
// format output
Log.d(TAG, "Lat: " +  String.format("%.4f", wgs84Point.getY()) + ", Lon: " + String.format("%.4f", wgs84Point.getX()));
```

You can find a simple example of this in the [show callout](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-android/tree/master/show-callout) sample.

Comment: how can i calculate the angle between two coordinate in android ?

Comment: can you please help me here  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237257/how-to-calculate-new-point-coordinates-from-distance-and-angle-using-arcgis-runt